# Having issues passing data with Livewire using 2 components

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I would like to pass data from a livewire component A to a Livewire component B. The goal is to open a social icon bar when required.

Here is my setup:

Component 1 class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;


class SocialShareBar extends Component
{
    public $show;
    protected $listeners = ['openSharePopup' => 'openSharePopup'];


    public function mount() {
        $this->show = false;
    }

    public function openSharePopup() {
        $this->show = true;
        $this->emit('openPopup', ['show' => $this->show ]);
    //Hoping to emit to the component B here
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.social-share-bar');
    }

}
```

Component B:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;


class SharePopup extends Component
{
    public $show;
    protected $listeners = ['openPopup' => 'render'];
   //I have hoping to catch the "emit" event here

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.popups.share-popup', ['show'=> true]);
    }

}
```

One component is in the "app.blade.php" main layout file and the other component is in footer.blade.php of Laravel(which is passed itselt to the app.blade.php file.

Each file residing in its own livewire location:
resources\views\livewire\popups\share-popup
resources\views\livewire\social-share-bar

I am currently unable to catch the below event in the second component:

```
 protected $listeners = ['openPopup' => 'render'];
```

Could the problem be the "protected" scope?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the second component a Livewire component, or a Blade component? Are they both rendered on the same page? What does the second component class look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question to better describe the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the second component to get data from the first component, you have to pass in data from the first components event, and listen for it in the seccond one.

You already pass inn the data from component A here,

```php
$this->emit('openPopup', ['show' => $this->show ]);
```

So all you need to do is listen for it in component B,

```php
class SharePopup extends Component
{
    public $show;

    protected $listeners = ['openPopup'];

    public function openPopup($show)
    {
        $this->show = $show;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.popups.share-popup');
    }
}
```

Then inside the view of component B, if you want to use Alpine, you'd do it like this,

```html
<div x-data="{ show: $wire.entangle('show') }" x-show="show"></div>
```

Comment: You are a king! I did not even find it in the doc !!! I loooked for ages. So in fact the { open: $wire.entangle('show') takes the variable form php and bind it (somehow) into a JS variable!! This is just so weird. I am really struggling with Livewre after playing so much with vue js. Thank you so much!